# What the mean of $\mathbb{I}$ in equation (7)?

Tags: functions, notation

[image]

I try to understanding this paper. In equation (7), I don't know the symbol "$\mathbb{I}$" mean. What the "$\mathbb{I}$" mean? Is that identity matrix? In the paper is not explained what "$\mathbb{I}$" mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain why they use exactly that symbol (maybe it's just  because \mathbb{1} doesn't work as expected), but the similar $\unicode{x1D7D9}_A$ is often used in the same meaning as others use $\chi_A$: a function that is $1$ for arguments in $A$, and $0$ outside $A$ (called "indicator function", or sometimes "characteristic function", but the latter is unfortunate in probability theory).